# Texture sampling coordinates seemingly scaled by factor of 2 in OpenGL/SDL2 tutorial

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, textures, sdl-2

I wrote a simple OpenGL program to sample a 256x256 PNG texture and render it on a rectangle in a window. I relied heavily on a tutorial for this. When I followed the tutorial almost directly (making minimal changes so as to use SDL2 for [x]), the texture did not render correctly and seemed to be somehow scaled down by a factor of 2. Here is the first version of the source code, as well as a screenshot of the results:

```cpp
// Link statically with GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC

// Headers
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_opengl.h>

// Shader sources
const GLchar* vertexSource = R"glsl(
    #version 150 core
    in vec2 position;
    in vec2 color;
    out vec2 Color;
    void main()
    {
        Color = color;
        gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
)glsl";
const GLchar* fragmentSource = R"glsl(
    #version 150 core
    in vec2 Color;
    out vec4 outColor;
    uniform sampler2D tex;
    void main()
    {
        outColor = texture(tex,Color);
    }
)glsl";

int main()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);

    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    // Create Vertex Array Object
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    // Create a Vertex Buffer Object and copy the vertex data to it
    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
//         x      y     u     v
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Top-left
         0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // Top-right
         0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Bottom-right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f // Bottom-left
    };

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Create an element array
    GLuint ebo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);

    GLuint elements[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0
    };

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Create and compile the vertex shader
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // Create and compile the fragment shader
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    // Link the vertex and fragment shader into a shader program
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    // Specify the layout of the vertex data
    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

    GLint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

    GLuint tex;
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    SDL_Surface* surface = IMG_Load("../textures/16x16-sb-ascii.png");

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, surface->w, surface->h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 

    bool running = true;
    while (running)
    {
        SDL_Event windowEvent;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&windowEvent))
        {
            switch (windowEvent.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                running = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Clear the screen to black
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Draw a rectangle from the 2 triangles using 6 indices
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        // Swap buffers
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }

    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ebo);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

[Initial results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz7uW.png)
[image]

For reference, here is the actual texture file:

[Original texture file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nC4E.png)

As you can see, the texture appears to have been quadrupled in the different quadrants of the rectangle, with the lower two copies inexplicably being thoroughly corrupted.

As one might expect, normalizing all the texture coordinates to 0.5 produces a single copy of the texture at the intended scale, although many strange yellow/blue artifacts are still visible, as are some very subtle noisy artifacts around the edges:

```cpp
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
//         x      y     u     v
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Top-left
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, // Top-right
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, // Bottom-right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f // Bottom-left
    };
```

[Results after scaling down the coordinates.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OLfn.png)
[image]

I'm doing this on a Dell laptop which came with Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS pre-installed. My graphics card is an Intel UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2).

Running glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version" gives the following result: OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.2.8.

Any help with either the scaling or the blue/yellow artifacts would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your texture is loaded as 16-bit grayscale+alpha, but your `glTexImage2D` call expects an RGBA data. Either load the texture as 32-bit RGBA, or change the `glTexImage2D` format parameters to `GL_RG`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated texture image is a luminance/alpha image and has just one color channel and one alpha channel. Thus you have to use the format `GL_RG` when you specify the 2 dimensional texture image by [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml):

```cpp
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RG, surface->w, surface->h, 0, 
             GL_RG, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);
```

---

Either set a [Swizzle mask](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture#Swizzle_mask) to read the green and blue color from the red color channel and the alpha value from the green color channel:

```cpp
GLint swizzleMask[] = {GL_RED, GL_RED, GL_RED, GL_GREEN};
glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_RGBA, swizzleMask);
```

or use [Swizzling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling) to get the red color channel and the alpha channel when you do the texture lookup in the fragment shader:

```c
#version 150 core

in vec2 Color;
out vec4 outColor;
uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{
    outColor = texture(tex,Color).rrrg;
}
```

Comment: The actual issue shown is definitively not unpack alignmet one - and with the image width at 256, every line willl be perfectly aligned now matter how many bytes each pixel takes.

Comment: Yes,  The issue is the format. And I think @Yakov Galks observation of the format being Luminance Alpha re-interpreted as RGBA would totally result in the observed pattern.

Comment: I know. But that doesn't change the fact that a) the suggested unpack alignment in this answer is not relevant for this question (won't hurt of course and is true for the general case) and b) that the suggested format of `GL_RED` in this is also not correct for this case. The fact that `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA` is removed doesn't imply that such image formats don't exist anymore, and @Yakov Galka's recommendation og `GL_RG` is the correct way to solve this, maybe one could mention texture swizzle masks to restore the luminance-alpha interpetation.

Comment: I'd actually prefer the [swizzle masks of the texture object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture#Swizzle_mask) as it keeps this stuff local to the texture object and does not require a special-case shader. And it's basically free in the hardware anyway.